# show an Image on Click of a LinkButton Control

Tags: asp.net

```
How to show an image in ContentPlaceHolder4 on click of a Link Button which is placed on ContentPlaceHolder3.
```

I Have a Master Page and one content page. On master page i have a link INSTRUMENTS by clicking on which i am redirected to content page INSTRUMENTS. Now i have 10 LINK BUTTON controls on my Content Page and i want on the click of each link button corresponding image should open on same content page but in different CntentPlaceHolder. Please  guide me how to add code for Link Button Click and how to render iamge on click of Link Button.
Following is the code i have added till now.

```
**This is My Master Page**


    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 162px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div> <img src="IMAGES/main.png" style="background-color: #99FF99; border-top-color: #800000; width: 1082px; height: 105px;" />
    </div>  &nbsp;
    <a href="HOME.aspx">HOME</a>&nbsp;<a href="INSTRUMENTS.aspx">INSTRUMENTS</a>&nbsp;<a href="LOGIN.aspx">LOGIN</a>&nbsp; 
&nbsp;<a href="ADRESS.aspx">ADDRESS</a>&nbsp;
 <table style="width: 100%; height: 288px; margin-top: 11px;">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#FF0066" align="center" class="style2" 
                style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#33CCCC" class="style1">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

   </body>
</html>

**This is My Content Page**

    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="INSTRUMENTS.aspx.cs" Inherits="INSTRUMENTS" %>

 <asp:Content id="content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
     <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </asp:Content> 
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" Runat="Server">

    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  OnClick="lkbutton_click">Sitar</asp:LinkButton><br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">Harmonium</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server">Tabla</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server">Drum</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server">Guitar</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server">Sarod</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton7" runat="server">Flute</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton8" runat="server">Santoor</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton9" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton9_Click">Keyboard</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton10" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>


</asp:Content>
<asp:content ID ="C2" ContentPlaceHolderID ="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="Server">
<asp:Image ID ="I1" ImageUrl ="~/IMAGES/F.png" >

<asp:Image />

</asp:content>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your design page use like this.

```html
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder4" Runat="Server">
    <img id="img1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

and in code behind link button click event like below:

```html
protected void lkbutton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        img1.Src = "~/images/sonata-logo.png";
    }
```

i tested it it's working fine.
but put the correct path of image then only it will show.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" width="250px" height="250"> 
<img runat="server" id="IL"src="~/Class/Adds/0/4.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

With this you can change the picture with server code.

```
il.SRC = "~/Class/Adds/0/7.jpg"
```